# llamar una funcion en el login de laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, autenticación

Estoy trabajando con laravel 5.5 y quiero llama a una función cada vez que un usuario se logueo y es autenticado en laravel, he estado buscando y no encuentro nada. 
y la pregunta final es
¿llama a una función en laravel cuando es logueo o autenticado?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $redirectTo = '/home';
    //protected $redirectTo = 'Solicitude_estado';
    protected $redirectTo = 'dashboard';



    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        echo "como esta tu";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas para hacerlo, asumiendo que quieras llamar la función una vez el usuario haya sido autenticado correctamente. Yo utilizaría el método `authenticated()` que está en el trait AuthenticatesUsers, para realizar lo que necesite, o para llamar a la otra función desde ahí, dependiendo lo que vaya a hacer, basta con incluir la función (que está definida vacía en el trait) en el controlador de login:

```
/**
 * The user has been authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed  $user
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    //
}
```

También es importante que mires el método `sendLoginResponse()` del mismo trait, para que veas lo que ocurre cuando se utiliza `authenticated()`:

```
/**
 * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}
```

Comment: Puede usar uno de los eventos de Autenticación también como **Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login**

Comment: Sí, por eso dije que hay muchas formas de hacerlo, pero no sé que tan familiar sea el OP con ciertas funcionalidades.

Comment: mucha gracias por su ayuda,aunque  le falto poner la libreria ***use Illuminate\Http\Request;*** , me estaba generado error